# How to fix previously renamed and Override existing migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-migration, rails-migrations

I have two models first is Course and another is Lesson. First we have table **course_lessons** with migration **xxxxxxxx_course_lessons** with some fields after that I have rename this **course_lessons** table to **lessons**. It is working fine for me.
But After that I have again add **course_lesseons** table create migration and override the existing migration and because of that my next all migration break.

How can I fix this migration error?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your best option for now is dropping your database and migrations and start over again. It's better to not rename migrations. If you have a migration runned and you don't like it, you can do a rollback with: `rake db:rollback` this will rollback your database to the previous version.(this will not put back tables if you delete them!)
Once you did a rollback, you can rename the migration and run: `rake db:migrate` again.

Another option would be to delete all the migration files. If the database is good for now, anyone else who starts the project can load the database from schema with: `rake db:schema:load`

Comment: Thank You, For response, your suggestion is good to drop database or load from schema file.